# How to train Google Inception-v3 model with smaller dataset?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

Hi guys~ I'm a newbie in Tensorflow.

I searched for several days and couldn't find similar question on stackoverflow

The goal is that I want to train Google Inception-v3 model with a **smaller** ILSVRC2012 image dataset,

because the dataset size is 138G and take too much training time (around 2 weeks for eight GPUs)

The only sample code I found is from

the tutorial of Udacity course "Introduction to Machine Learning" - SVM - A smaller Training set

```
features_train = features_train[:len(features_train)/100] 
labels_train = labels_train[:len(labels_train)/100]
```

**What is the code to reduce the dataset size for Tensorflow, bazel or python???**

Thx a lot~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discussion with others

I finally figure out how to do this in a simple way

The data set download from imagenet is around 400 GB with 1000 training data folder

You can take **one percent** of it ( 1000 * 0.01 = 10 folders)

and transfer it to tfrecords or other tensorflow readable file format